# Repeating entries in the event viewer

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-event-log

Running Windows Server 2019 standard in a four node cluster.  In the event viewer -> windows logs -> Application  there are repeating entries.

The message is
'Windows Installer reconfigured the product.' followed by different application and products

There are hundreds of these messages - and there is no consistent delay between the group of entries.

Most of the Microsoft entries have the last part of the message read
'Installation success or error status: 0.'

Questions are -

1. Are these entries supposed to be there?
2. Why are they continuously re-configuring the software?
3. What can I do to resolve this possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal if something uses the Win32_Product WMI class. Some products such as SCCM have a similar WMI class that shadows what Win32_Product does but without this side effect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/windows-installer-reconfigured-all-applications

"Win32_product class isn't query optimized. Queries such as select * from Win32_Product where (name like 'Sniffer%') require WMI to use the MSI provider to enumerate all of the installed products and then parse the full list sequentially to handle the where clause. This process also starts a consistency check of packages installed, verifying, and repairing the install. An account with only user privileges may cause delay in application launch and an event 11708 stating an installation failure, as the user account may not have access to quite a few locations.

"Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms is a much lighter and effective way to do so, which avoids the calls to do a resiliency check, especially in a locked down environment. So when using Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms, we won't be calling on msiprov.dll and won't be initiating a resiliency check."